# Is rm -f in a php shell command safe?

Tags: php, shell, rm

No user input here, but I still want to check that this is safe:

```
<?php system('rm /tmp/my-cache/3600/* -f');
```

Is there any circumstance that could result in that deleting files from another directory?  For example what would happen if that directory didn't exist for some reason?

I think it's safe, but I've been bitten by a similar (yet completely different) bit of code before, in a cron job that runs every minute:

```
cd /tmp/my-cache/3600
find . -maxdepth 1 -mmin +61 -type f -delete
```

Under some circumstances that folder didn't exist, which meant `find` deleted any files in the home directory instead!

(The fix was to wrap it inside a `if [ -d "/tmp/my-cache/3600" ]; then` / `fi` block)

Like I say, I think the php `system` call is safe, I just want to check there isn't an extenuating circumstance I don't know about which could cause problems?

Comment: "-f, --force: ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt" http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rm.1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `rm -f /tmp/my-cache/3600/*` is safe, if `/tmp/my-cache/3600/` is empty, nothing will be removed.

The only difference with `rm /tmp/my-cache/3600/*` (no `-f`) is that you won't get this warning:

> No such file or directory

...but that does not mean something has been removed. According to [**`rm`'s man page**](https://man.openbsd.org/rm.1), this happens with the `-f` option:

> If the file does not exist, do not display a diagnostic message or modify the exit status to reflect an error.

...so `rm` behaves like it has deleted something even when it hasn't.

---

#### `find` is safe too!

Instead of checking if the directory exists, then `cd` into it, and then run `find`, you should use the following `find` command:

```
find /tmp/my-cache/3600 -maxdepth 1 -mmin +61 -type f -delete
```

...because it already does the check for you:

> find: /tmp/my-cache/3600: No such file or directory

Comment: As an aside, I've always put the -f flag at the end, but 99% of the code samples I see put it directly after the rm command.  Is there any practical difference?

Comment: @Codemonkey Putting the `-f` flag (or any other option) at the end does not work with BSD's `rm`. You would get: `rm: -f: No such file or directory`. So for compatibility reasons it's a good practice to put your options as first parameters.